# Cocos2d-x SimpleAudioEngine SoundEffects getting cut while playing

Tags: android, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using SimpleAudioEngine Cocos2d-x for playing sound effects in my game. 
  While playing multiple sounds effects sometimes the sound gets cut in middle and sounds weird. This mainly happens in Android build of cocos2d-x, Anyone has faced this issue?

Is there a way to get more logs out of SimpleAudioEngine?
Any other alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might need to try preloading sound effects, at beginning of each stage of your program because it need to load the sound effect before it can play it.
You could create a waiting scene that helps you to loads all your assets.
using `SimpleAudioEngine preloadEffect` might be the answer for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Android (on iOS it worked fine). Changing SimpleAudioEngine to the experimental AudioEngine plus preloading sounds helped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But you were a bit late in answering

Comment: You don't think it might help someone else then? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the code is using SoundProof library within. Apparently it has limitations based on the KHz of the Sound.